# Makefile: dynamically dispatch to other makefiles

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a number of subdirectories, with Makefiles inside, and I want a "master" Makefile that basically calls Makefiles in those directories:

```
Makefile
foo/Makefile
bar/Makefile
```

So that typing `make foo` in root directory is equivalent to `cd foo && make`. I can write simple Makefile to acieve this:

```
foo:
    cd foo && make

bar:
    cd bar && make
```

But I don't want to list those subdirectories, so I can add new directory with Makefile without having to modify "master" Makefile.

Answer (score 1):

I think `make` is probably not the best tool for this specific problem.  Why not a shell script?

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $1 && make
```

If you're really determined to do it with only `make` you could use a makefile like this:

```
DIRS=$(patsubst %/,%,$(wildcard */))
.PHONY: $(DIRS)
$(DIRS):
    @cd $@ && $(MAKE)
```

Comment: In your second example you need an `all: $(DIRS)` or similar before the DIRS rule, otherwise only the first one will be built.

Comment: @MadScientist the question specifically asked for a way to have `make foo` do something.  There was no requirement for a default behavior of "build everything if I type only `make`". If anything, it might make more sense for `make` with no argument to print the list of directories available.

Comment: `make -j16 proj1 proj2` is reason enough to eschew shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
subdirs := $(shell find * -name Makefile | sed /\/Makefile$//)

$(subdirs):
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

A couple of quick points:

- you should not call `make` directly from within a makefile.  Use `$(MAKE)` instead.
- `$(MAKE) -C dir` does the same thing as `cd dir && make`
- if your makefiles are guaranteed to be exactly one level down, use `ls */Makefile` instead of `find * -name Makefile`.   The posted solution will find all makefiles in sub-directories, which may not be what you want.
- you should be careful that one of the sub-directory names does not conflict with any of your other target names in the main makefile.   Some sort of directory naming / target naming convention would be required for that.

Comment: Same comment as above, about needing an `all` target.